# How to deploy a kubernetes cluster on multiple physical machines in the best manner?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, raspberry-pi, cluster-computing, minikube

I recently finished a project where I created an App consisting of several docker containers. The purpose of the app was to collect some data and safe it to an databank and also allow user interactions over an simple web gui. The app was hosted on four different Raspberry Pi's and it was possible to collect data from all physicial maschines through an api. Further you could do some simple machine learning tasks like calculating anomalies in the sensor data of the Pi's.

Now I'm trying to take the next step and using kubernetes for some load balancing and remote updates. My main goal is to remote update all raspberries from my master node. Which, in theory, would be a very handy feature. Also I want to share the ressources of the Pi's within the cluster for calculations.

I read a lot about Kubernets, Minikube, K3's, Kind and all the different approaches to set up an Kubernetes cluster, but feel like I am missing "a last puzzle piece".

So from what I understood I need an approach which allows me to set up an local (because all machines are laying on my desk/ no cloud needed) multi node cluster. My master node would be (idealy) my laptop, running Ubuntu in a virtual machine. My rasberry's would be my slave/worker nodes. If I would want to update my cluster I can use the kubernetes remote update functionality.

So my question out of this would be: Does it makes sense to use several rasberries as nodes in a kubernetes cluster and to manage them from one master node (laptop) and do you have any suggestions about the way to achieve this setup.

I usally dont like those question not containing any specific code or questions by myself, but feel like an simple hint could accelerate my project noteable. If it's the wrong place please feel free to delete this question.

Best regards

Comment: What do you mean by "remote update all raspberries from my master node"? What kind of updates are you talking about?

Comment: Like described here: https://platform9.com/blog/kubernetes-upgrade-the-definitive-guide-to-do-it-yourself/ . So in my application an update would be some changes in my docker containers for example. For example every Pi hosts my webserver. I can connect via ssh and I a am able to control my whole network using that webserver. If one Pi fails I can connect to the webserver of another Pi. Now to update all webservers I think I could use Kubernetes to distribute the newer "webserver docker images and settings" among my network.

Comment: The link to blog you provided explains how to upgrade kubernetes cluster, that is k8s as application. But from what you said, (correct me if I am wrong) you don't want to upgrade cluster but you want to upgrage your applications that would be running on k8s. Is that correct?

Comment: First of all, thanks for your time! Yes what you said is correct. I want to upgrade my application which is running on k8's.  Maybe that's wrong, but I thought updating my k8's nodes would automatically update my cluster since there are new updates for my nodes availible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't mention which rpi models you are using, but I assume you are not using rpi zeros.

> My main goal is to remote update all raspberries from my master node.

Assuming that by that you mean updating your applications running in kubernetes that is installed on rpi then keep reading. Otherwise ignore all I wrote, and what you probably need is ansible or other simmilar provisioning/configuration-management/application-deployment tool.

Now answering to your question:

> Does it makes sense to use several rasberries as nodes in a kubernetes cluster

yes, this is why people created k3s, so such setup is possible using less resources.

> and to manage them from one master node (laptop)

assuming you will be using it for learning purpouses then why not. It is possible, but just be aware that when master node goes down (e.g. when you turn off your laptop), all cluster goes down (or at least api-server communication so you wont be able to change cluster's state). Also make sure you are using bridge networking interface for your VM so it is visible in your local network as a standalone instance.

> and do you have any suggestions about the way to achieve this setup.

installing k3s on all nodes would be the easiest in your case. There are plenty of resources on the internet explaining how to achieve it.

---

One last thing I would like to explain is the thing with updates.

Speaking of kubernetes updates you need to know that kubernetes doesn't update itself automatically. You need to explicitly update it. New k8s version is beeing released every 3 months that sometimes "breaks" things and backward compatibility is not possible (so always read [changelog](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/CHANGELOG) before updating stuff because rollbacks may not be possible unless you backed up an etcd cluster earlier).

Speaking of updating applications - To run your app all you do is send yaml files describing your application to k8s and it handles the rest. So if you want to update your app just update the tag on container image to newer version and k8s will handle the updates. [Read here](https://www.weave.works/blog/kubernetes-deployment-strategies) more about update strategies in k8s.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I think I've got enough to think about for now. And yes I dont use Pi Zeros but RPI 4. They only got 1 GB RAM but to use them as worker nodes should be fine I guess?! Also the hint with the laptop as master node is very helpfull. I didn't think about that by now. Thanks again!